# How to create an unlogged table in postgresql using GORM

Tags: go-gorm

The expected request is:

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE <table name>()
```

The `.Set("gorm:table_options", " UNLOGGED ")` will add `UNLOGGED` at the end of request. But it is required between `CREATE` and `TABLE`.

Is there a way to do this using GORM?